# Display miles-per-hour and kilometres per hour together?

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement, weather-api

I want to display miles-per-hour and kilometres per hour together. is that possible?

How should I implement the kilometres per hour calculation and display it together?

```js
function getMiles (knots) {

    var mph = (knots * 1.15078);
    var speed = Math.round(mph);


    if (speed < 50) {
        return speed + console.log('mhp ');
    }
    if (speed > 50) {
        return speed + console.log('mph , wind can be too strong today ');
    };
}getMiles()
```

Answer (score 1):

You returning to early, add the kph one and concatenate it.

```js
const wind = knots => {
  const miles = Math.round(knots * 1.15078)
  const kph = Math.round(knots * 1.852)

  return `${miles} mph / ${kph} kph ` + (
    miles > 50 ? 'wind can be too strong today' : ''
  )
}

console.log(wind(80))
```

Comment: I see. very elegant code. It works the same idea with Celcius and Fahrenheit? just add the calculation and return it right? thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can return an object containing both mph and kph, then display it any way you want;

```
function getSpeed (knots) {
  const mph = Math.round(knots * 1.15078);
  const kph = Math.round(knots * 1.852000888);

  return { mph, kph };
}

let speed = getSpeed(50);
console.log(`mph: ${speed.mph}, kph: ${speed.kph}`);
// mph: 58, kph: 93
```